# AH02040: Certificate Verification: Certificate Chain too long (chain has 0 certificates, but maximum allowed are only -1) where does the -1 come from?

Tags: apache

Has anyone seen this Apache HTTP server (version 2.4.57 deployed on RHEL 9.2 operating system) error message when they have configured web-browsers (clients) to authenticate using certificates:

```
AH02040: Certificate Verification: Certificate Chain too long (chain has 0 certificates, but maximum allowed are only -1)
```

The statement "chain has 0 certificates" is correct, however, where does the -1 come from? Am I missing a configuration option?

I have adjusted the SSLVerifyDepth configuration directive. However, I don't think this has any bearing on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that I needed to move  tags (and all the configuration directives contained within them), from the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file, to enable configured web-browsers (clients) to authenticate successfully using TLS certificates.